# how to pass data to more number of activities

Tags: android, android-intent

I would like to pass data from one activity to another.If it is two or three activities we can send data via intent.suppose more number of activities are present (approximately 20).how can i pass data from first activity to last activity?

i want to go Activity A-->B-->C-->D-->......Y-->Z

if we send data via intent(put Extra) that is worst method.

is there any other way to send data?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I would use [SharedPreferences](https://www.google.com.np/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAAahUKEwji5o6W7evGAhXB46YKHRxmCRM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Freference%2Fandroid%2Fcontent%2FSharedPreferences.html&ei=IAmuVeLWHMHHmwWczKWYAQ&usg=AFQjCNFyaMlF7pqBKbWPbXr7H1Wg4gKaoA&sig2=dDf-sbfm3C5qsYyeK7NT-g) for this.

This will be easier because, we can change it anywhere in any activity and access them as needed. And we don't need to pass on each and every activity transition.

**Simple example:**
To set value in shared preference

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putString("name", "Nabin");
 editor.putInt("idName", 12);
 editor.commit();
```

And retrieve as

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
if (restoredText != null) {
  String name = prefs.getString("name", "No name defined");//"No name defined" is the default value.
  int idName = prefs.getInt("idName", 0); //0 is the default value.
}
```

You can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example) more about it.

Comment: shared preference is fine is there any other way

Comment: Do you have any problem with this approach considering your requirement?

Comment: no its fine i am going for this but just wanted to know any other way

Comment: @YUGANDHAR Database is another way. But much more complex to do

Answer (score 0):

If you need some data to multiple activities, Just save data into `SharedPreference` and you will be able to access to all activities.
[Here](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-shared-preferences.html) is full tutorial.

**Save Data**

```
    // Create object of SharedPreferences.
     SharedPreferences sharedPref= getSharedPreferences("mypref", 0);
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor= sharedPref.edit();
    //put your value
     editor.putString("name", strName);
     editor.putString("pwd", strPass);
     editor.commit();  //commits your edits
```

**Retrieve Data**

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPref= getSharedPreferences("mypref", 0);
 String name = sharedPref.getString("name", "");
 String password = sharedPref.getString("pwd", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's not a must case to use activities, you can change activities to fragments, attach them to same activity, cache your data in activity and get it from fragments.